# Automate Canvas (jqcharts)Pie charts, bar graphs using selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, html5-canvas, report, ui-automation

I am planning to work on automating Canvas reports (jqcharts, xyplot, bar charts,pie chart) with Selenium WebDriver.

Before stating working on it, I was reading the reviews on forum on report automation, so I thought I should get some feedback on the following questions:

1. Did anyone get the success in automating jqcharts with selenium webdriver?
2. If so, what are the major challenges you faced in automating the charts, and how you overcome them?

Please find an attached sample xy charter DOM of the report is also attached (refer `ReportDom.xml`)

DOM of the report

```
<div style="height: 400px; width: 800px; position: relative;" id="chartView" class="jqplot-target"><canvas width="800" height="400" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;" class="jqplot-base-canvas"></canvas><div class="jqplot-title" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 800px; text-align: left;">Process Instances</div><div style="position: absolute; width: 800px; height: 43px; left: 0px; bottom: 0px;" class="jqplot-axis jqplot-xaxis"><div class="jqplot-xaxis-label" style="position: absolute; left: 403.5px; bottom: 0px;">Priority</div><canvas width="23" height="15" style="width: 23px; height: 15px; text-align: left; position: absolute; left: 175.167px;" class="jqplot-xaxis-tick"></canvas><canvas width="46" height="15" style="width: 46px; height: 15px; text-align: left; position: absolute; left: 405px;" class="jqplot-xaxis-tick"></canvas><canvas width="27" height="15" style="width: 27px; height: 15px; text-align: left; position: absolute; left: 655.833px;" class="jqplot-xaxis-tick"></canvas></div><div class="jqplot-axis jqplot-yaxis" style="position: absolute; height: 400px; width: 56px; left: 0px; top: 0px;"><div class="jqplot-yaxis-label" style="position: absolute; width: 49px; top: 177px; left: 0px;">Count</div><canvas width="7" height="15" style="width: 7px; height: 15px; text-align: left; position: absolute; top: 339.5px;" class="jqplot-yaxis-tick"></canvas><canvas width="7" height="15" style="width: 7px; height: 15px; text-align: left; position: absolute; top: 293.5px;" class="jqplot-yaxis-tick"></canvas><canvas width="7" height="15" style="width: 7px; height: 15px; text-align: left; position: absolute; top: 247.5px;" class="jqplot-yaxis-tick"></canvas><canvas width="7" height="15" style="width: 7px; height: 15px; text-align: left; position: absolute; top: 201.5px;" class="jqplot-yaxis-tick"></canvas><canvas width="7" height="15" style="width: 7px; height: 15px; text-align: left; position: absolute; top: 155.5px;" class="jqplot-yaxis-tick"></canvas><canvas width="7" height="15" style="width: 7px; height: 15px; text-align: left; position: absolute; top: 109.5px;" class="jqplot-yaxis-tick"></canvas><canvas width="7" height="15" style="width: 7px; height: 15px; text-align: left; position: absolute; top: 63.5px;" class="jqplot-yaxis-tick"></canvas><canvas width="7" height="15" style="width: 7px; height: 15px; text-align: left; position: absolute; top: 17.5px;" class="jqplot-yaxis-tick"></canvas></div><canvas width="800" height="400" class="jqplot-grid-canvas" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;"></canvas><canvas width="724" height="322" style="position: absolute; left: 66px; top: 25px;" class="jqplot-series-shadowCanvas"></canvas><canvas width="724" height="322" style="position: absolute; left: 66px; top: 25px;" class="jqplot-series-canvas"></canvas><div class="jqplot-cursor-tooltip" style="position: absolute; right: 16px; bottom: 59px; display: none;"></div><canvas width="724" height="322" style="position: absolute; left: 66px; top: 25px;" class="jqplot-highlight-canvas"></canvas><div class="jqplot-highlighter-tooltip" style="position: absolute; display: none;"></div><canvas width="724" height="322" style="position: absolute; left: 66px; top: 25px;" class="jqplot-lineRenderer-highlight-canvas"></canvas><canvas width="724" height="322" style="position: absolute; left: 66px; top: 25px; cursor: crosshair;" class="jqplot-event-canvas"></canvas><table style="position: absolute; font-size: 11px; z-index: 3; left: 790px; top: 161.5px;" class="jqplot-table-legend"><tbody><tr class="jqplot-table-legend"><td class="jqplot-table-legend jqplot-table-legend-swatch jqplot-seriesToggle" style="text-align: center; padding-top: 0px;"><div class="jqplot-table-legend-swatch-outline"><div class="jqplot-table-legend-swatch" style="background-color: rgb(75, 178, 197); border-color: rgb(75, 178, 197);"></div></div></td><td class="jqplot-table-legend jqplot-table-legend-label jqplot-seriesToggle" style="padding-top: 0px;">Series 1</td></tr></tbody></table></div>
```

Comment: Where you successful in using Selenium to test your jqcharts? I am attempting to do a similar thing (using qjplot) and would appreciate any information you found.